# No sound in wine

Tags: wine, dragon-ball-xenoverse

I'm currently using the latest `wine1.7` build from the wine ppa and am running Linux Mint 17.2 and can't run DB:XV through Steam with sound. The Steam browser can make sound, but DB:XV cannot. Running `dbxv.exe` starts up Steam anyway and doesn't have any effect. What am I doing wrong?